# IK weird behavior

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I always use a simple IK setup for the arms :

- Wrist IK ( Target Elbow ) + Elbow IK ( target Shoulder 2 )
- Wrist + Copy rotation modifier with Wrist IK as target

It always worked on thousand of model but not this one , and i don't understand why...

When i apply the first IK ( Wrist IK > Target elbow chain 2 ) , it works as planned , but as soon i add the second IK ( Elbow IK > Targer SHoulder 2 Chain 1) , the IK setup becomes unusable.

On all other models , the arm will remain straight , and the Elbow IK position will lead the direction of the elbow , but in this case , it breaks everthing.

I am not looking for another IK setup , i do know other more advanced setups , i just need to understand why it works on 99,99% of my models , but not this one.

The file: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/o129NwJV#link
PS: Add an IK contraint on Shoulder 2 targeting Elbow IK , chain 1 to see the problem.

Comment: Please upload your file to the official site at https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/311598/edit) your question here and paste the link into it. At the moment the file will be deleted as soon as anyone downloads it which means that anyone reading your question in future will be unable to see your file.

Comment: What a fucking retarded system

Comment: That's how some of those external file sharing sites work. I presume it's done so that they can keep their storage requirements down.

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Once added, the upper arm tracks elbow IK and the forearm tracks the wrist.  Is it possible that you targeted the wrong bone with your upper arm constraint, or set the wrong chain length?  Targeting elbow IK is okay because elbow is unparented, doesn't depend upon upper arm.

Comment: The problem once applied ( IK elbow targeting Shoulder 2 ) IK elbow then moves the wrist , and it's not supposed to do that , it's wrong. It's not a mistake on my part , i did this hundreds of time.

Comment: "IK elbow then moves the wrist" Sorry, I cannot reproduce that problem using 4.0.1.